# Xbox One and Xbox 360 same account

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one

Is it possible, without messing up my account, to play my Xbox One at my home and for my brother to play my Xbox 360 at his home on my account? Will it ruin my account if we do so?

Comment: It's still only 1 account even if it is played on mutliple systems. I doubt this will be able to work.

Comment: its actually working right now witch its kinda nerve raking cause i don't know if its gonna mess my account up what do u think ?

Comment: As listed in my answer, @VanBuzzKill is slightly incorrect. You can be connected to one Xbox 360 and one Xbox one at the same time, but the intention is that it is still you signing in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Your microsoft account can be signed in to both a Xbox 360 and a Xbox One at the same time, without any issues.

As a secondary issue you face, it is against the terms of service to share your xbox account with another person. While I am personally doubtful that Microsoft would act against you, you should be aware that using differant WiFi connections suggests access from differant IP addresses, which in turn could raise a red flag.

Comment: ok thank you very much i will most likely just not do it then. just to play it safe i appreciate the help a lot thank u!!

Comment: I wpuld recommend jumping on their website, and going to "contact support". You can opt to talk to a microsoft rep,and the waits usually 5-10 minutes. Tell them exactly what you want to do, and if they say you can, make a copy of the conversation / save it to an email or cloud drive like google. IF they have trouble later, simple proof that a tech support rep said it was OK will get you a "ok but dont do it again".